# How pass two argument to houses_path (:arg1 => 4, :arg2 => 56)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Passing the method in a View i got the error

```
`undefined local variable or method arg1 for # HousesController:0xbbb7e38>`
```

But when i use only one argument work fine.

My route is defined like that:

> MyAplication::Application.routes.draw do
>
> resources :houses
>      math ':controller/:action/:arg1/:arg2'
>
> end

I new in RoR, but i have searching, i can't figure out what i doing wrong.

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the params in your controller as follows:

```
arg1 = params[:arg1]
arg2 = params[:arg2]
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help can you mark the answer as correct (only if it really is of course :-)

Comment: I don't know why, but it works. i was used: @arg1 = params[:arg1], thanks again